# Support for great-grandchildren (Insight.Database)

Tags: insight.database

Using Insight.Database, I can query for an object with children and its grandchildren:

`var someObject = connection.Query("SomeStoredProc", new {ParentId = id},        Query.Returns(Some<Parent>.Records)
                .ThenChildren(Some<Child>.Records)
                .ThenChildren(Some<Grandchild>.Records,
                        parents: parent=> parent.Children,
                        into: (child, grandchildren) => child.Grandchildren = grandchildren));`

I have a set of tables
Parent -> Child -> Grandchild -> Great-Grandchild

I tried using RecordId, ParentId, ChildRecords attribute to no avail. Also, all my classes are decorated with [BindChildren(BindChildrenFor.All)].

Is there a way I have the populate the Great-Grandchildren? Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The pattern is similar to grandchildren. For the parents: selector, you just need to use a SelectMany to get the full list of grandchildren.

(At least, that's how it's supposed to work...)

```
var someObject = connection.Query("SomeStoredProc", new {ParentId = id},
        Query.Returns(Some<Parent>.Records)
            .ThenChildren(Some<Child>.Records)
            .ThenChildren(Some<Grandchild>.Records,
                    parents: parent=> parent.Children,
                    into: (child, grandchildren) => child.Grandchildren = grandchildren)
            .ThenChildren(Some<GreatGrandchild>.Records,
                    parents: parent=> parent.Children.SelectMany(c => c.Grandchildren)),
                    into: (grandchild, greatgrantchildren) => grandchild.greatgrantchildren= greatgrantchildren));
```

);